# IServiceCollection - это локатор сервисов?

Tags: asp.net, шаблоны-проектирования, dependency-injection

Вот я добавляю сервис IRepository<Network> в контейнер сервисов, а потом класс `AdminController` использует его. Эта реализация является антипаттерн `локатор сервисов`?

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    ...

    services.AddTransient<IRepository<Network>, EFRepository<Network>>();

    ...
}
```

```
public class AdminController : Controller
{
    private readonly IRepository<Network> _dbContext;

    public AdminController(IRepository<Network> dbContext)
    {
        _dbContext = dbContext;
    }
}
```

Comment: Вопрос не очень ясен. Речь про антипаттерн "Service Locator"?

Comment: Да, речь про него.

Comment: Если внутри `AdminController` будет использоваться `IServiceCollection`, тогда это будет антипаттерн. В показанном коде этого нет.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Нет. Это не "сервис локатор". "сервис локатор" - когда вы таскаете контейнер как зависимость, то есть код вида

```
public AdminController(IServiceProvider services)
{
    _dbContext = services.GetRequiredService<IRepository<Network>>;
}
```

При таком подходе нельзя узнать что AdminController использует IRepository просто глядя на описание класса. Придется лезть в исходники и изучать тело всего класса (мало ли где там извлекается сервис из локатора).

А пока у вас зависимости явные и DI контейнер просто заполняет эти зависимости (но не прокидывается сам), то это правильный подход.